# ASP.NET + Connecting/Interacting to a Web Service

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET Web Application that needs to connect to/interact with an existing set of web services. This is going to sound like a vague question, but, I'm not sure of the address to bind to.

When I look at the server on which the web services reside on,  I have found a .wsdl file. I have used this .wsdl file to build my request/response structure. But now, I want to actually test interacting with it. I opened up the .WSGen file and the root attribute looks like:

```
<WSDLGenConfig WSDLGenVersion="3.0" 
  serviceName="ApplicationWS" 
  COMObjectPath="C:\Application\Application\Bin\service.dll" 
  listenerURI="http://www.somedomain.com/ApplicationWS/" 
  listenerType="ASP" 
  XSDSchemaNS="2001" 
  definitionsTNS="http://localhost/ApplicationWS/wsdl/" 
  schemaTNS="http://localhost/ApplicationWS/type/" 
  soapBodyNS="http://localhost/ApplicationWS/message/" 
  soapActionURI="http://localhost/ApplicationWS/action/" 
  characterSet="UTF-8" 
  outputPath="C:\Application\The Web Service" >
```

Personally, I'm used to just adding a service reference through Visual Studio. But I'm not sure what I should be trying to bind to. Can I use any of the information above to determine the service's address? If not, how can I determine the address of the service if I have access to the server that they are installed on? [I know this is an odd question]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Web Reference to use the web service.

[Adding Web Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx.aspx)

Comment: My problem is, I don't know the URL of the Web service. How can I find it on the web server?

Comment: Without knowing your setup the only thing I can say is search for all .asmx pages on the folder structure. Then look on IIS on to find where those files are mapped.